# Exclude folder except one subfolder via regular expression in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to add a Resource Filter in Eclipse to exclude a folder named `target` including all it's files and subfolders **except** exactly one of this subfolders (`target/scala-2.11/classes_managed`).

Here is the regex I used for this (including examples for subdirectories):
https://regex101.com/r/aQ2qM1/1

In the referenced example it seems the regex works fine.
However when I apply this regex in Eclipse it does not work.

What's the correct way to write the regex so it works in Eclipse?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: So it looks like Eclipse doesn't support look aheads. What's the problem with `^target/scala-2.11/classes_managed/.*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to get all fancy with regular expressions, you can tell eclipse to "Include only" the Folders with a Name matching:

```
target/scala-2.11/classes_managed
```

That will exclude all the files that you wish.

Comment: But this will also exclude other folders that are on the same level (root level) like the `target` folder.

Comment: You can add the resource filter directly to the folder target instead of the root folder.

Comment: Thanks, your last comment was the hint I needed!